# How to play an audio file starting at a specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, vlc

I want to play an audio file at a specific duration, for example, start it at 1:00 minute or at 500 milliseconds using the media player module in python.

```
    import vlc
    song = vlc.MediaPlayer('song.mp3')
    song.play()
```

now with song.play() i can play the file but only from the beginning, so is there any way to start it at a specific duration?

Comment: Can't you just use the `time` module?

Comment: What is the "media player module in python"? As far as I know, there is no one main media player. Could you please show some code that you have already tried? ([Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: ""import vlc"" the vlc module in python, i can do ""song= vlc.MediaPlayer(song.mp3)"" to get the file and to play it i need to do"" song.play()"", so what im asking is how can i start the file at a specific duration? also @MikeSmith what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`set_time()`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#set_time) method of the [`MediaPlayer`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html) object:

```
import vlc
song = vlc.MediaPlayer('song.mp3')
song.play()
song.set_time(10000)    # play at 10,000 ms (10 seconds)
```

There is also [`set_position()`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#set_position) which works with values between 0.0 and 1.0:

```
song.set_position(0.5)   # half way through media file
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin a cat and in addition to the accepted answer, you can also use the `--start-time` and `--stop-time` options on the `Media` instance.
i.e.

```
import vlc
import time
url = "file:///home/rolf/BBB.ogv"

playing = set([1,2,3,4])
instance=vlc.Instance()
player=instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new(url)
media.add_option('start-time=600.00') # start at 600 seconds (10 minutes)
media.add_option('stop-time=605.00') # for 5 seconds
player.set_media(media)
player.play()
time.sleep(0.1) # wait briefly for it to start
while True:
    state = player.get_state()
    if state not in playing:
        break
```

Note: `--run-time` also exists
Use `vlc -H` on the command line, for a wealth of options.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Rolf is the only version that worked for me using python-vlc on Raspbian on the Pi. Digging into the VLC API for the set_position method, you find 'This might not work depending on the underlying input format and protocol.' - it didn't for me. The only seek method I have found that worked for me is the example using the Media instance.

Comment: seems more of a comment than answer